# How can I define a metric and plotting a function using that metric in Mathematica?

Tags: mathematica-online

I have tried to solve this but my problem wasn't completely solved.I want to plot a function `f(t_) := {1,t,0}` using the metric `g = {{y^2, 0, y}, {0, exp[z], 0}, {y, 0, 1}}`. Here is the coding in Mathematica which was i have tried for plotting a function `f(t_) := {1,t,0}` but it doesn't shows the plot of a function.

```
metric[x_,y_,z_] := {{y^2, 0, y}, {0, exp[z], 0}, {y, 0, 1}}

ParametricPlot3D[metric[1,t,0], {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Hue[.6],  
Thickness[.02]}]
```

[image]

Could someone please give me some pointers on how to do this?

Comment: Use `Exp` in place of `exp` (uppercase the letter `E`).

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

Built-in symbols have names beginning with capital letters, see [Wolfram Language Syntax](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Syntax.html) and [Language Overview](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LanguageOverview.html), also [The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheFourKindsOfBracketingInTheWolframLanguage.html), [Some General Notations and Conventions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeGeneralNotationsAndConventions.html), [Wolfram Predictive Interface](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WolframPredictiveInterface.html).

```
metric[x_, y_, z_] := {{y^2, 0, y}, {0, Exp[z], 0}, {y, 0, 1}}

ParametricPlot3D[metric[1, t, 0], {t, -1, 5}, 
PlotStyle -> {Hue[.6], Thickness[.02]}]
```

[image]