# NDsolve doesnt work

Tags: differential-equations

```
R=5;
g=9.8;
sol = NDsolve[{theta''[t]==-g/m*sin[theta[t]],theta[0]==20,theta'[0]==0},theta,{t,0,100}]
Plot[theta[t]/.sol,{t,0,100}]
```

The code above gives me error and it doesn't plot anything.
[image]

Comment: Use `NDSolve` rather than `NDsolve`. Use `Sin` rather than `sin`. You need to assign a value to `m`.

Comment: Also, don't type a lot of code without testing, evaluate *all of it* and wonder why it didn't work.  Take each piece separately.

Answer (score 0):

See also [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126516/how-can-i-define-a-metric-and-plotting-a-function-using-that-metric-in-mathemati/126520#126520) for some very important advice about Built-in symbols and so on.

```
g = 9.8;
m = 10^3;
sol = NDSolve[{theta''[t] == -g/m*Sin[theta[t]], theta[0] == 20, 
theta'[0] == 0}, theta, {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[theta[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

Since the variable **R** is not used anywhere, I have leftout this piece of Code.